# Return list of remaining elements in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two lists:

```cs
List<int> data1 = new List<int> {1,2};
List<int> data2 = new List<int>{1,2,3,4};
```

I want to create a new list:

```cs
List<int> data3
```

which intersects data1 and data2 and and contains elements as {3,4}

Comment: And where is your attempt?`What problem do you have with your own code?

Comment: are the data types different on purpose?

Comment: The "duplicate" answer is incorrect for this question. `Intersect()` would return `{1, 2}` but the question asks for `{3, 4}`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I changed it. Does it fit better now?

Comment: @MongZhu Yep, OK now

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use `Except`

```
var result = data2.Except(data1);
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PAN675)